# Geostatistics: Covariance vs Semivariance

Tags: covariance, stationarity, assumptions, geostatistics, variogram

I am confused by the following page in Geostatistics for
Environmental Scientists, Webster & Oliver:

[image: Webster & Oliver]

#### My understanding

Given locations specified by a vector $\mathbf{x}$, we assume an underlying distribution $Z(\mathbf{x})$ behind each observation. To obtain the given covariance function (4.10), we have assumed second order stationarity (i.e. all the $Z(\mathbf{x})$ have equal mean, variance, and a few other things). The author argues this is troublesome since the mean often varies across a region. To remedy this, we instead only assume the expectation value for the difference in mean to be 0, which should hold for close enough by locations.

#### My confusion

It seems to me that replacing covariances with variances of differences allows us to relax the requirement $E(Z(\mathbf{x})) = \text{const.}$ to $E(Z(\mathbf{x})) - E(Z(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h})) = 0$, which seems useful (and perhaps even necessary) to conducting meaningful geostatistics.
However, I don't see how we are "released from the constraints of second order stationarity", aren't we still assuming constant variance across the space of interest ? Were the authors simply referring to the relaxed constraint on the means, or am I missing something ?